# Binomial coefficient intervals (inequality)

Tags: inequality, binomial-coefficients

For given $N$, $x$ and $k$ such that $0\leq x<N$ and $2\leq k\leq
\left\lfloor \frac{N+1-2x}{2}\right\rfloor $, does it exist $p,$  $2\leq
p\leq \left\lfloor \frac{N+1}{2}\right\rfloor $ such that

\begin{align}
& \frac{(N+1-p)(N-p)}{2}\leq \frac{(N+1-x-k)(N-x-k)}{2}+\frac{(x+1)x}{2}<\frac{(N+1-p)(N-p)}{2}+\frac{p(p-1)}{2}+p+1-x
\end{align}

Comment: Since all your binomial coefficients have $2$ as lower index, I suggest that you use $\binom n2=\frac{n(n-1)}2$ and reformulate your question as one of purely algebraic inequalities.

Comment: seems that $p=k+x$ makes the trick.